# What log is emmitted in Palantir Foundry Audit Logs when a change is made in Control Panel?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

I want to monitor when anyone makes a change to the Foundry configuration through Control Panel. What log types from Audit Logs should I be focusing on so I can be alerted in such an event?